# CC Transaction in iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, authentication, transactions

Sorry I have some sort of question about iphone apps, this is my first time developing with IOS devices that's why I need some suggestions.

1. Is it allowed to create an apps for IOS devices that contains a transaction with credit card, such as booking reservation or on-line payment/banking?
2. Lets say that user should log-in first before doing any transaction, for Authentication between the device and web server, any secure way to do this? I mean when logging-in from the device, something like authentication for 1 time login. Any tips or best practice/approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, there is that Square app where they give away the reader which plugs into the audio jack, so others have
   2) SSL for encrypted xfer?